# Is ApplicationComponent deprecated?

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

I just started using Dagger Hilt for dependency injection on Android and I get a warning on Android Studio saying `'ApplicationComponent' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java`.

I didn't find anything related to this warning while Googling, is it actually deprecated or is it safe to use?

I also noticed on Dagger's website that they don't mention it anywhere in the "[Migrating to Hilt](https://dagger.dev/hilt/migration-guide)" guide and they use `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)` which seems to be working but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

`ApplicationComponent` being renamed to `SingletonComponent`, to allow usage of Hilt in non-Android Gradle modules [link](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.28.2)

Answer (score 20):

> Is ApplicationComponent deprecated?

Yes, it is deprecated.

Instead of `ApplicationComponent`, you can use `SingletonComponent`.
This is an Hilt component for singleton bindings