# error: cannot find symbol @dagger.hilt.InstallIn(value = {ApplicationComponent.class})

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

After upgrading dagger hilt(version: `2.31-alpha`) `ApplicationComponent.class` can not find.
What is the alternative for a `Component` like RoomDatabase?

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
class RoomModule() {
private val DATABASE_NAME = "salat_time"

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRoomDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
    appContext,
    AppDatabase::class.java,
    DATABASE_NAME
).createFromAsset("db/$DATABASE_NAME.sqlite").build()

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideLocalSalatRepository(database: AppDatabase) = LocalSalatRepository(database)

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideDistrictRepository(database: AppDatabase) = DistrictRepository(database)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65266636/is-applicationcomponent-deprecated/65272745#65272745

Answer (score 257, accepted):

`ApplicationComponent` is Deprecated in Dagger Version [2.30](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/dagger-2.30) 
`ApplicationComponent` removed in Dagger Version [2.31](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/dagger-2.31) 
Alternatively `SingletonComponent` should be used instead of `ApplicationComponent`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class RoomModule() {
   . . .
}
```

Comment: **Note:** For those who are still unable to find `SingletonComponent` while importing, it is in `dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent` package. All other `Components` are in `dagger.hilt.android.components` package.

Answer (score 47):

**ApplicationComponent** is renamed to **SingletonComponent**

Answer (score 10):

Just import:

```
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
```

and annotate your module as:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
```

Because ApplicationComponent is removed in the newer version of daggerHilt and I'm using these dependencies for dagger hilt within app level gradle file:

```
//Dagger - Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31-alpha"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha"

implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
```

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationComponent is Deprecated.

@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)

Update hilt dependency and use SingletonComponent
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)

```
//Hilt

implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.43.2'
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.43.2'
kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

---

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
abstract class RoomModule
{
@Binds
@Singleton
abstract fun binding(
    obj: UserImpl
):user}




ApplicationComponent has been replaced by SingletonComponent.

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class RoomModule {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, please be sure to update to the [latest](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#setup) hilt version, or else you will be stuck with ****KaptExecution Error****.

Current version `ext.hilt_version = '2.33-beta'`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need @InstallIn, you can always disable explicitly.

```
Alternatively, the check can be disabled at the individual module level by annotating the module with @DisableInstallInCheck.
```

As mentioned in https://dagger.dev/hilt/flags.html

Like

```
@DisableInstallInCheck
@Module
class MyAwesomeModule
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun mProvidersTaskDatabase(app: Application) : TaskDataBase{
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            app,
            TaskDataBase::class.java,
            "Task_db"
        ).build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun mProvidersTaskRepository (dataBase: TaskDataBase) : TaskRepository{
        return TaskRepositoryImpl(dataBase.mTaskDao)
    }
}
```